# X-axis labels not showing on chart render in FusionChart

Tags: php, fusioncharts

X axis labels are not showing by default when chart renders. On clicking of legend (Say T2), it shows. See below pics for details.

[image: Pic 1:]

[image: Pic 2:]

Pic 1: Labels not showing.
Pic 2: On clicking of  legend (T2), labels appear

Can someone tell what is the issue here. I do not see any error in console of chart debugger

Answer (score 0):

Tried replicating the problem and the X-axis labels are rendered correctly after rotating in this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/xykvfru8/

```
"labelDisplay": "rotate"
```

Would you please replicate your issue in the above sample and share?

Comment: I already have this attribute in the chart, it is just to change orientation of the labels.

Comment: I apprehend that the space is not enough for the labels to be displayed correctly. Please share the DataSource fed to the chart and also please let me know the FusionCharts version you are using. Kindly try and replicate the problem with your dataSource in this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/xykvfru8/ and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

In this mode, you can wrap long x-axis labels into multiple lines. If enough space is not available in a chart, this mode will automatically trim labels, add ellipses at the end, and show tooltips for such labels. To wrap the data labels, set the labelDisplay attribute as wrap. Refer to the code below:

```
{
   "chart": {
      "rotateLabels": "0",
      "labelDisplay": "wrap"
   }
}
```

Here is the live demo code -

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'mscolumn2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Sales Trends",
        "subcaption": "2016 - 2017",
        "xaxisname": "Month",
        "yaxisname": "Revenue",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "labelDisplay": "wrap"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "12-Jan-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "02-Feb-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "15-Mar-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "10-Apr-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "22-May-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "11-Jun-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "21-Jul-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "02-Aug-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "12-Sep-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "18-Oct-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "14-Nov-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "28-Dec-2016"
          },
          {
            "label": "21-Jan-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "11-Feb-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "06-Mar-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "14-Apr-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "11-May-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "28-Jun-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "30-Jul-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "19-Aug-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "23-Sep-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "22-Oct-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "19-Nov-2017"
          },
          {
            "label": "22-Dec-2017"
          }
        ]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
        "data": [{
            "value": "27400"
          },
          {
            "value": "29800"
          },
          {
            "value": "25800"
          },
          {
            "value": "26800"
          },
          {
            "value": "29600"
          },
          {
            "value": "32600"
          },
          {
            "value": "31800"
          },
          {
            "value": "36700"
          },
          {
            "value": "29700"
          },
          {
            "value": "31900"
          },
          {
            "value": "34800"
          },
          {
            "value": "24800"
          },
          {
            "value": "26300"
          },
          {
            "value": "31800"
          },
          {
            "value": "30900"
          },
          {
            "value": "33000"
          },
          {
            "value": "36200"
          },
          {
            "value": "32100"
          },
          {
            "value": "37500"
          },
          {
            "value": "38500"
          },
          {
            "value": "35400"
          },
          {
            "value": "38200"
          },
          {
            "value": "33300"
          },
          {
            "value": "38300"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  });

  revenueChart.render();
});
```

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/h9s4p7cu/2/

Refer the docs - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/data-labels